# Salesforce Org activity for a specific time window

Tags: platform-activity

Is there a way to go and look into all the activities in a Salesforce org/Platform for a time window.

We had a scenario where in an Account was not present at a specific time and then it was present. So, essentially I am trying to find out the details on the activities for the window when the Account was not in SFDC.

Comment: What do you define as an "Activity"?

Comment: Hi Sebastin,Anything a user does in SFDC. I understand this will be wide range depending on the users in the org but with the scenario I explained, I am looking at anything that was done on the Account object to start with.

Comment: Something like this? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_monitorsetup.htm&language=en_US&type=0